# Can i test facebook audience network for my unpublished app?

Tags: android, facebook-ads-api

Is this possible? Maybe there are some test PLACEMENT_ID for this?
I just want to play around and see capability of facebook native ads, but i can't create placement id for my app without "Applying for Audience Network", which requires url from google play.

Answer (score 2):

You can use these ids

```
public String BANNER_PLACEMENT_ID = "549167759165615_549192715829786";
public String INT_PLACEMENT_ID = "549167759165615_549190905829967";
public String RV_PLACEMENT_ID = "549167759165615_549192132496511";
public String NATIVE_PLACEMENT_ID = "549167759165615_551513495597708";
```

for testing purpose **facebook audience network**

Comment: From where did you get this?

Answer (score 0):

Just recently Facebook Audience Network allowed publishers/users to test with Facebook Ads without "Applying for Audience Network" or submitting an application.

You can start from here, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network Assuming that you have already signed into Facebook, Click on "Get Started" and create a Facebook App if you haven't yet. Enter the Audience Network tab on the left side panel. Then simply just create an ad placement and you can start testing from there with the newly created ad placement.

Note, your placements will only serve Facebook Ads to the developers/admins of the app until Audience Network approves your app.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can check this [Link Here](http://%20https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/setting-up/test/test-device/)

```
AdView(this, "IMG_16_9_APP_INSTALL#YOUR_PLACEMENT_ID", AdSize.BANNER_HEIGHT_50);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to facebook documentation you can use test ads as follow:

`TEST_AD_TYPE#YOUR_PLACEMENT_ID`

You can find `test ad type` from this link below:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/setting-up/test/test-device

And then just place your ad placement id after # then It will something look like this:

'IMG_16_9_APP_INSTALL#28123678890986787880_2231119230931372'